# Flawed induction proof / finding error

Tags: real-analysis, induction, fake-proofs

Find the error in the following induction proof

Claim: $k$ arbitrary points in a plane always lie on one line

Base case. for $k=1$ and $k=2$ this is apparently correct

Assumption: Claim already shown for $k$ points

Induction step: Let $k+1$ points, $P_1,...,P_{k+1}$ be given, due to the assumption the points $P_1,...,P_{k}$ lie on the **line g** and $P_2,...,P_{k+1}$ lie on **line h**, since $P_2$ and $P_k$ both lie on **line g** and **line h** , it follows that $g=h$, thus  $P_1,...,P_{k+1}$ are all on one line.

So I am not sure whether my assumption is correct but I think the error lies in the case k=3, which was never checked in the base case? I do not know how to argue here correctly.

Comment: Hint: $k$ is not used consistently between the base case and the inductive step. For what value of $k$ does the proof purportedly demonstrate that $3$ arbitrary points in a plane lie on one line, and what does the proof say, exactly?

Comment: Still, why are several points on the same line just because some of them are on one line and some of them are on another line. Work through the $3$-point case carefully!

Comment: You are correct: the argument fails in the $k=3$ case since $P_2=P_{k-1}$.

Comment: @SteveKass, can I just say in case of three points $P_1,P_2,P_3$, I would have two cases either they are all on one line, or they form a triangle, in the second case, each point would be on the same line with one other point at the time? I do not know how to formulate it more "mathematically beautiful"

Comment: It fails because $P_1 ....P_k$ and $P_2.....P_{k+1}$ are not shown to lie on the *same* line. Having shown true tor 1 and 2 then for 3, the points lie on lines, but not (necessarily) on the same line and the union of the two is not (necessarily) a line.

Comment: @TomCollinge: thank you! :)

Comment: Adding to what Tom said, note that it *is* correct to conclude that for distinct points $P_i$, that $P_1\dots P_k$ and $P_2\dots P_{k+1}$ being separately collinear implies that all the points are on the *same* line if $k>2$, because in that case both sets of points contain both $P_{k-1}$ and $P_k$ and must therefore be on the specific line determined by those two points. But when $k=2$, $P_{k-1}$ is not one of the points $P_2$ through $P_{k+1}$.

Comment: @SteveKass: thank you very much for the detailed explanation